# Sort dates in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I want to list dates from the most current date to the oldest date.

I don't want to use `Collections.sort()`so I made my own method.

When I do this :

```
List<Livre> maBibliotheque = new ArrayList<Livre>();
boolean tri = false;
int born = maBibliotheque.size();            

             while (tri == false) 
             {
                 tri = true ;  
             for (int i=0; i<born-1;i++) 
             {
                 if ( maBibliotheque.get(i).getNewPeriode().compareTo(maBibliotheque.get(i+1).getNewPeriode())>0){
                     Livre livre = maBibliotheque.get(i);
                     maBibliotheque.set(i, maBibliotheque.get(i+1)); 
                     maBibliotheque.set(i+1,livre);  

                     tri = false ; }

             }
             born -= born;
             }
```

It works perfectly, but from the oldest to the newest date, but I want the otherwise.
I change this line to

```
 if ( maBibliotheque.get(i).getNewPeriode().compareTo(maBibliotheque.get(i+1).getNewPeriode())<0){
```

But it's doesn't make anything, no sort dates in this case. Please help

Comment: `I don't want to use Collections.soft` You want to replace a working, tested, efficient O(n log n), sort() with a broken, untested, inefficient o(n^2) sort. Why?

Comment: Consider writing a comparator that does this and using `Collections.sort()` anyway. That implementation is done very well and it'd be quite a project to do something yourself that comes anywhere near it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort from oldest to newest, then reverse it with `Collections.reverse(maBibliotheque);`

Comment: The last element doesn't work ! :/ 
We should may be add something else to the code

Comment: This is terrible advice!

Comment: I added the line like you told me and I changed : born=born-1;  And it works now perfectly ! Really thank you !!! :)

Comment: Wait, so you don't want to use `Collections.sort`, but `Collections.reverse` is ok? That... doesn't seem to make much sense...

Answer (score 2):

To reverse the order, replace `> 0` with `< 0`

Doesn't

```
 born -= born;
```

do the same as

```
 born = 0;
```

I suspect this isn't needed.

---

This

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    List<Livre> maBibliotheque = new ArrayList<Livre>();
    maBibliotheque.add(new Livre("aaa"));
    maBibliotheque.add(new Livre("abb"));
    maBibliotheque.add(new Livre("bbb"));
    maBibliotheque.add(new Livre("000"));
    boolean tri;
    int born = maBibliotheque.size();

    do {
        tri = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < born - 1; i++) {
            if (maBibliotheque.get(i).getNewPeriode().compareTo(maBibliotheque.get(i + 1).getNewPeriode()) > 0) {
                Livre livre = maBibliotheque.get(i);
                maBibliotheque.set(i, maBibliotheque.get(i + 1));
                maBibliotheque.set(i + 1, livre);
                tri = false;
            }

        }
    } while (!tri);

    System.out.println("increasing: " + maBibliotheque);

    do {
        tri = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < born - 1; i++) {
            if (maBibliotheque.get(i).getNewPeriode().compareTo(maBibliotheque.get(i + 1).getNewPeriode()) < 0) {
                Livre livre = maBibliotheque.get(i);
                maBibliotheque.set(i, maBibliotheque.get(i + 1));
                maBibliotheque.set(i + 1, livre);
                tri = false;
            }

        }
    } while (!tri);

    System.out.println("decreasing: " + maBibliotheque);
}

static class Livre {
    private final String newPeriode;

    Livre(String newPeriode) {
        this.newPeriode = newPeriode;
    }

    public String getNewPeriode() {
        return newPeriode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Livre{" +
                "newPeriode='" + newPeriode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

prints

```
increasing: [Livre{newPeriode='000'}, Livre{newPeriode='aaa'}, Livre{newPeriode='abb'}, Livre{newPeriode='bbb'}]
decreasing: [Livre{newPeriode='bbb'}, Livre{newPeriode='abb'}, Livre{newPeriode='aaa'}, Livre{newPeriode='000'}]
```

Comment: @Humoule That is because your sort doesn't work. You have to remove the `born -= born;` See my update

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing a `Comparator`.  You set a field in the Comparator object that can tell it whether to sort Ascending or Descending, then call `Collections.sort(maBibliotheque, new MyComparator(MyComparator.DESC))`

Demo (adjust generics as needed, and if, as in this case, you know that you're comparing with a specific field use `o1.getField().compareTo(o2.getField())`.  Alternately, you could implement `Comparable` in your Object and just call `Collections.sort(List)`, but that's not as flexible.

```
   public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
   {
      public static final int ASC = 0;
      public static final int DESC = 1; 

      private final int sortOrder;

      public MyComparator(int sortOrder)
      {
         this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
      }

      /* (non-Javadoc)
       * @see java.util.Comparator#compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
       */
      @Override
      public int compare(String o1, String o2)
      {
         switch(this.sortOrder)
         {
            case ASC:
               return  o1.compareTo(o2);

            case DESC:
               return o2.compareTo(o1);
         }
         return 0;
      }
   }
```